# Jacoco with Gradle 0.10.0: Remote object doesn't exist

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, build.gradle

**UPDATE Oct 21, 2014:**
The issue has been confirmed as fixed by using buildtools 21.

**UPDATE SEPT 18, 2014:**
The [issue's status](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174&thanks=69174&ts=1398894143) has been updated to `FutureRelease`.

**UPDATE:**
I have heard that this may not work with Dagger, and since Espresso uses Dagger, it might be causing some issues. A [bug was submitted](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174&thanks=69174&ts=1398894143) to the Gradle team.

---

Google recently updated their [Gradle implementation to 0.10.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). One of the things they now offer is Jacoco support. To do this, they mention setting the following:

```
testCoverageEnabled = true
```

Into your build type. Now when I run my Espresso tests (using `connectedCheck`), I get an error right as I start to run the `:connectedAndroidTest` task that states:

```
Tests on HTC One - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 1080x1920 - 4.2.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.VerifyError'
01:38:31 E/Device: Error during Sync: Remote object doesn't exist!
null
java.io.IOException: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.pullFile(ConnectedDevice.java:114)
at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:158)
at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pullFile(SyncService.java:314)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.pullFile(Device.java:849)
at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.pullFile(ConnectedDevice.java:107)
... 8 more
:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
```

Here are the parts I have changed in the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
        ...
    }
    ...
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            ...
        }
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there any other piece of `build.gradle` file that I need to update in order to get Jacoco working?

The error mentions that a "remote object" doesn't exist. Usually I attribute this to the emulator being out of sync and a restart would fix it. But I've tried that and it isn't worked either. Any ideas what the error is trying to tell me?

Comment: I'm running into the same exact issue (not using Dagger or Espresso). The tests run on a real device (Nexus 4, 4.3.1). I am seeing a ClassNotFoundException for CoverageTransformer (part of JaCoCo Agent) in logcat..

Comment: That's failing in the pullFile method, I think it's trying to pull a file that it doesn't have permission, try on an emulator (since it acts as a rooted device) and see if it can pull the file there.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I used a rooted device and restarted adb in root mode `adb root`, still seeing the same error.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this? I am running into the same issue on both a rooted device and emulators.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as well.  Exact same exception; also on an HTC One.

Comment: Are you still facing this 0.12.2?

Comment: See update. Looks like this will be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try This One...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1" // Must Require

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packagename" <Change it>
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}
```